# Calling API asynchronously in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I need to call a API 5000 times, Presently with the current logic its happening synchronously one by one. Is there any way to call it asynchronously without actually waiting for the API response. Code Below.

```
            while (true)
            {                 
                using (HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient())
                {// ***Want to call the API Asynchronously***
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
                    {
                        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                        dt = dt.AddSeconds(-dt.Second);
                        Log[] data1 = new Log[]
                    {                           
                        log =new Log(){LogID=Guid.NewGuid(),LogLevel=new LogLevel(){ },Message="Maverick_Messgaes",Source="Maverick",StackTrace="Maverick Started",
                         Time=dt,Traceid="1"},
                };
                        var response4 = httpclient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:8095/api/Log/PostAsync", data1).Result;
                    }

                }
                //logstack.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(log.Message + log.Time + " ");
                Thread.Sleep(120000);
                Console.WriteLine("  " + " 5000 messages Sent.. Iterating Again" + "" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }

    }
```

Comment: maybe make a await method and call it several times ?

Comment: What you are looking for is not asynchronous programming, it's parallel, and they are very different.

Answer (score 2):

You could replace your for-loop with a `Parallel.For` loop to run the code within the loop in parallel.

This guide provides a good introduction with examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-for-loop

In its simplest form, it would look like:

```
    Parallel.For(0, 5000, i =>
    {
       // code within existing for-loop goes here...
    });
```

If you're concerned about the number of concurrent tasks, there are overloads that take a `ParallelOptions` parameter, within which you can specify the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Can you please show the same with my example as i am new to Parallel programming not much aware how to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!  What value i can provide in MaxDegreeOfParallelism. suppose if i provide 5000 max, will 5000 tasks gets created and each will execute once?

Comment: @KshitijKeshri No - basically, the max degree of parallelism controls how many tasks are performed at the same time, which is limited by the number of cores you have. If you are not concerned about the number of concurrent tasks, you don't need to specify it and the run-time environment will use as many cores as it can.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are not doing anything with the result so I am assuming you don't need to return it.

You need to make your method async and await the HttpClient synchronous call just like the code below.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Continuing iteration " + i);
                PostData(client);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    static async void PostData(HttpClient client)
    { 
        await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com.ph");
        Console.WriteLine("Async call done");
    }
```

Comment: That's still going to fire off the requests sequentially.

Comment: It fires sequentially but asynchronously.

Comment: But it says in the question "without actually waiting for the API response".

Comment: My code does not wait for a response, you see it waiting for the result and assigning it to a variable?

Comment: What do you think `await` does?

Comment: As per my current code its calling the API sequentially, one by one, i want to achieve hit and forget scenario. Once the code call the API, it should  call at the same time without expecting any result

Comment: modified answer

Comment: Has the same problem as the deleted answer, "Except you probably don't want to fire off 5k requests all at once..."

Comment: Also note [_"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_5)

Comment: what if I pass the client?